# Taylor expanding $\frac{e^x}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How can you taylor expand $$\frac{e^x}{x}$$

Can it be expanded at $x = 0$? Can it be expanded as $x \to 0$?

Comment: You can't if I recall correctl'y, the 1 term in $e^x$ makes it an issue.

Comment: the Taylor-expansion can be done about any point except $x=0$. The convergence is guaranteed in the interval $(0,2a)$ if you expand around $x=a$.

Comment: Since the function is undefined at $0$, you cannot do a taylor expansion of it around $0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dividing the standard Taylor series for $e^x$ by $x$ (term-by-term) would give you the so called [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) (which can include negative powers of $x$) of $\tfrac{e^x}{x}$:

$$\frac{e^x}{x} = \sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{x} + 1 + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^3}{24} + \frac{x^4}{120} + \ldots$$

It converges for $x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 3):

What we get for $\dfrac{e^x}x$ is a [Laurent Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series):
$$
\frac1x+1+\frac x{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^3}{4!}+\cdots
$$